# $n = a^2 + b^2, \; p^3 = a^3+b^3, \; m^3+2p^3 = 3mn$ then prove that $m = a+b$

Tags: linear-algebra, problem-solving

If $a$ and $b$ both are positive integers then

> $m = a+b, \;n = a^2 + b^2, \; p^3 = a^3+b^3$ Then show that $ m^3+2p^3 = 3mn$.

This is a easy problem to solve. Just substitute those values and show that.
But I can't find a way to solve this

> $n = a^2 + b^2, \; p^3 = a^3+b^3, \; m^3 + 2p^3 = 3mn$ Then prove that $m = a+b$ is a solution to the system.

Any hint will be helpful.

Comment: Check $a=0, b=-1, m = 2$.

Comment: Do you assume that $n,a,b,m,p$ are positive integers ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde It is not mentioned in the question. :O

Comment: Review the question and the assumptions made before. It is obviously worng.

Comment: @RezwanArefin As seen in my answer, even if they are positive integers the claim is false.

Comment: @MXYMXY You want to tell me that $m=\sqrt{3}-1$ is an integer ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde There is no condition that $m$ is a integer.

Comment: @MXYMXY Yes, and this is what I asked the OP, because otherwise it is obviously wrong.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Oh yes, I just copied and pasted, so I missed that. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You showed that if $m = a+b, \;n = a^2 + b^2, \; p^3 = a^3+b^3$ Then show that $ m^3+2p^3 = 3mn$.

Thus, imagine you are solving the cubic equation $x^3+2p^3=3xn$. Let one such solution be $x=m$.

From the upper statement, note that $m=a+b$ is a solution. Our proof is done.

Comment: Why? not only $m = \sqrt{3}-1$ satisfies but also $m=1+1$ satisfies that...

Comment: @RezwanArefin $m=1+1$ satisfies it  because that is what you proved in your first statement. My aim  is to show the second statement is false.

Comment: But can't there be multiple solutions? $m = \sqrt{3} -1$ can be a solution but why $m = 2$ is not a solution?

Comment: @RezwanArefin If there are multiple solutions, then there are solutions to $n = a^2 + b^2, \; p^3 = a^3+b^3, \; m^3 + 2p^3 = 3mn$ where $m \neq a+b$.

Comment: @RezwanArefin  $m=2$ is a solution. But so does $m=\sqrt{3}-1$. The fact that $m=a+b$ is a solution is what you showed in your first statement.

Comment: The problem is to show that there is a solution which is equals to $a+b$. 
But there can be another solution.

Comment: @RezwanArefin Then you should rephrase your question to prove that $m=a+b$ is a solution. Your statement -prove $m=a+b$- implies that it is the only solution.

Comment: @RezwanArefin Proving there is a solution equal to $a+b$ is a statement equivalent to your first.

Comment: But is there any way to prove it algebraically?

Comment: @RezwanArefin If your proved your first statement is equivalent to the second, the proof to the first statement is equal to the proof of the second statement. If you proved your first statement algebraically, you can prove the second algebraically.

Answer (score 0):

$$m^3+2p^3=3mn\implies m^3+2(a^3+b^3)=3m(a^2+b^2)$$

$$\iff m^3-3m(a^2+b^2)+2(a^3+b^3)=0$$

Let $m=u+v\implies m^3=u^3+v^3+3uvm\iff m^3-3m(uv)-(u^3+v^3)=0$

Comparing we get $u^3+v^3=-2(a^3+b^3)$ and $uv=a^2+b^2=u^3v^3=(a^2+b^2)^3$

So, $u^3,v^3$ are the roots of $$t^2+2(a^3+b^3)t+(a^2+b^2)^3=0\  \ \ \ (1)$$

But $a^3,b^3$ are in general not the roots of $(1)$